# Custom domain not updating wit modules

Tags: google-app-engine

I have one application hosted in google app engine.I mapped that application to a custom domain.My applicalation have 2 custom modules.Intially the modules in the custom domain are update by updating the app in GAE.But now i can't update the modules in custom domain by updating module in gae

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to edit the cname records of your domain ?